# How to create a shortcut to a folder to Documents

Tags: fedora, symlink

I have a folder in `/media/sf_fedora` which I want to access from `Documents` instead of going into `/media` each time, how can I create a shortcut. The 'Make Link' is grayed out in the Edit menu for some reason.

Comment: The reason "make link" is grayed out is because /media is not writable and "make link" from the "Edit" menu normally creates a link in the current directory. To create a link in another directory you need to use drag and drop.

Comment: @guss Why is /media not writable?

Comment: Because its a system folder and normal users are not allowed to write to system folders. Also - because its the folder that is used to auto-mount dynamically added devices, you don't won't to create static folders there because the mounting service is likely to overwrite them if it ever needs to mount a device with the same label as your static folder.

Comment: Really, if we are talking about latest Fedora the automount is in `/run/media/<user>/` folder. And `/media` is used for other purpose.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Open terminal and `ln -s /media/sf_fedora ~/Documents/sf_fedora` would create a symlink in `Documents` folder.

Comment: Also right clicking and dragging the sf_media folder into the Document folder should open a menu where one of the options is "make link".

Comment: @Guss It doesn't open a menu for some reason.

Comment: Another option is `cd ~/Documents && ln -s /media/sf_fedora`. I use it because I always forget which argument comes first: the folder I want a link for, or the path of the link to be created :)

Comment: @SkyDan: `ln` uses the same syntax as `cp`. From source, to destination.

Comment: @bahamat: Are you sure? `ln -s a b` will create a symbolic link `b` to `a`, so the target (`a`) comes first, while the source (`b`) comes after. In `cp a b` it's exactly the opposite: `a` is the source, while `b` is the target, in this order.

Comment: @FrancescoTurco: Really, `ln -s a b` will create a symbolic link `b` to `a`. So! The `b` is a target, where the link will be placed. And `a` is a source.

Comment: @m0nhawk: I see your point, but I used the "target" word as in ln(1) man page (see synopsis). The info pages is the same. For me, "target" is where you get when you try to access the symbolic link. You "start" with the symbolic link, and you "end" at the file the symbolic link points to.

Comment: @FrancescoTurco: think of it like this: `[cp|ln] something_that_exists something_that_does_not_exist`.

Comment: @orange: as don_crissti mentioned, I was incorrect in the way to get a drag menu - you need to hold ALT while left dragging.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Nautilus, it has a dedicated mouse+key combo for creating symlinks:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+*drag*

Alternatively, you can use either *middle (wheel) click drag* or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+*drag* to get a `move/copy/link` menu.

Comment: Nice alternative to the above answer: it's graphical, which is what the OP was looking for!