# Is it possible to make Nautilus use Mouse&Modifier to generate symbolic link under Wayland?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, wayland

I believe to recall that in the past I was able to use the same mouse behaviour as when moving a file with drag&drop +modifier key to then generate a symbolic link at the place of where I otherwise would have moved the file to. I cannot find this anymore (but maybe my mind betrays me and this was in my earlier incarnation as an OSX user).
And using Ctrl+Shift+M seems like an unnecessary, unintuitive step in between.

Note: under X windows it works as described in [How to create a shortcut to a folder to Documents](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52237/how-to-create-a-shortcut-to-a-folder-to-documents/52287#52287). 
but under Wayland it does not seem to work.

One question: is it already possible within Nautilus to achieve what I am looking for and if so how?
Other question: if not, can I configure Nautilus to do this?

Or: should this be a feature request to the developers?

Cheers!

Comment: thanks @don_crissti. maybe I am blind - would you give me any pointed to how?

Comment: get it. thanks. well, i tested and played - and found it works under x but not under wayland. so, i added this now to the question. thanks for your link!

Comment: yeah, looks like only `Alt` + drag works on wayland... it'll take probably at least a couple of years for gnome on wayland to be actually usable

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug.  I created an entry in Nautilus's bug database:

[can't create symbolic link using Ctrl+Shift+drag on Wayland](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/1302)